# Accessing array declared inside a class via object of that class

Tags: php, arrays, oop, variables

I have created a class named as MEMBERS. In this class I have declared an array as a member variable.

```
class member
{
public $arr_connections;
function connections($id)
{
    $query = mysql_query("Select * from connections where user_id = '$id'");
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $arr_connections[] = $info['connection_id'];
    }

}
}
```

Then I have created an object of this class as follow

```
 $user = new member();
```

After this I am calling the function as

```
$user->connections($user->id);
```

Next I am displaying the array

```
foreach($user->arr_connections as $mem_id)
{
            echo $mem_id;
            $person = new member($mem_id);
            echo "<a href = 'profile.php?id=$person->id'><img src = '$person->display_picture'/ width = 30 height = 30></a>";
}
```

This is not working. I guess my method is wrong. Some constructor was required. But I have to do this without constructor. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning it to the class property, because you're missing `$this->`. Change it into this and it should work for you:

```
$this->arr_connections[] = $info['connection_id'];
```